# VBA UDF ParamArray Sequence

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions, paramarray

I want to create a function that is almost exactly like SumIfs, but I'm having a hard time figuring our how to handle the ParamArray portion. I'm looking for a solution that allows the same Range1,Criteria1,Range2,Criteria2,...,Rangen,Criterian as the sum ifs but in my "SumIfsContains" function. I've attached the code for the singular case, "SumIfContains" so you can see my starting point:

```
Function SumIfContains(PhraseRange As Range, Criteria As String, SumRange As Range)
Dim element As Range

ElementCount = 0
For Each element In PhraseRange
    ElementCount = ElementCount + 1
Next element

Dim SumArray: ReDim SumArray(1 To 3, 1 To ElementCount)

ElementCount = 0
For Each element In SumRange
    ElementCount = ElementCount + 1
    SumArray(2, ElementCount) = element
Next element

ElementCount = 0
For Each element In PhraseRange
    ElementCount = ElementCount + 1
    SumArray(1, ElementCount) = element
    If InString(CStr(element), Criteria) Then
        SumArray(3, ElementCount) = SumArray(2, ElementCount)
    Else
        SumArray(3, ElementCount) = 0
    End If
Next element

SumIfContains = 0
For Item = 1 To ElementCount
    SumIfContains = SumIfContains + CDbl(SumArray(3, Item))
Next Item

End Function
```

Before I got an answer last night I came up with a working option as follows:

```
Function SumIfsContains(SumRange As Range, ParamArray Criteria() As Variant)
Dim element As Range
Dim cCriteria As String
Dim PhraseRange As Range

'Exit Function
Dim PhraseRangeArray(): ReDim PhraseRangeArray(LBound(Criteria()) To (((UBound(Criteria()) + 1) / 2) - 1))
Dim CriteriaArray(): ReDim CriteriaArray(LBound(Criteria()) To (((UBound(Criteria()) + 1) / 2) - 1))

CurrentPair = 0
For i = LBound(Criteria()) To UBound(Criteria())
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        PhraseRangeArray(CurrentPair) = Criteria(i)
    Else
        CriteriaArray(CurrentPair) = Criteria(i)
        CurrentPair = CurrentPair + 1
    End If
Next i

ElementCount = UBound(PhraseRangeArray(0))
Dim SumRng: ReDim SumRng(1 To ElementCount)
i = 1
For Each element In SumRange
    SumRng(i) = element
    i = i + 1
Next element
Dim SumArray: ReDim SumArray(0 To 2 + UBound(PhraseRangeArray), 1 To ElementCount)

For i = 1 To ElementCount
    SumArray(1, i) = SumRng(i)
    For RC = 2 To 2 + UBound(PhraseRangeArray)
        If InString(CStr(PhraseRangeArray(RC - 2)(i, 1)), CStr(CriteriaArray(RC - 2))) Then
            SumArray(RC, i) = 1
        Else
            SumArray(RC, i) = 0
        End If
    Next RC
    SumArray(0, i) = SumArray(1, i)
    For Mult = 2 To 2 + UBound(PhraseRangeArray)
        SumArray(0, i) = SumArray(0, i) * SumArray(Mult, i)
    Next Mult
Next i


SumIfsContains = 0
For Item = 1 To ElementCount
    SumIfsContains = SumIfsContains + CDbl(SumArray(0, Item))
Next Item

End Function
```

But I'm still curious how to make the Range/Criteria pair not simply be parced out of the "Criteria" array later.

[image]

Comment: `Range1, Criteria1, Range2, Criteria2, ...` they're not `ParamArray` parameters. I think you'd need a crap-ton of `Optional` parameters, kind of like `CallByName` does (with 30 optional parameters).

Comment: @Mat'sMug - `CallByName` actually takes a `ParamArray` - [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36316527/4088852).

Comment: @Comintern gah, I went by memory.... I meant `Application.Run` then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll note that for SUMIFS, unlike SUMIF, the data range comes first. That's key to your ParamArray:

```
Function SumIfContains(SumRange As Range, ParamArray criteria())
    Dim x                     As Long
    Dim n                     As Long
    Dim dTotal                As Double
    Dim bMatch                As Boolean

    ' check for criteria ranges
    For n = LBound(criteria) To UBound(criteria) Step 2
        If TypeName(criteria(n)) <> "Range" Then
            SumIfContains = CVErr(xlErrNum)
        End If
    Next n

    ' loop through each cell in sum range
    For x = 1 To SumRange.Cells.Count
        bMatch = True
        ' loop through criteria
        For n = LBound(criteria) To UBound(criteria) Step 2
            ' first item in pair is the range, second is the criterion
            If InStr(1, criteria(n).Cells(x).Value2, criteria(n + 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                ' if one doesn't match, set a flag and exit the loop
                bMatch = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next n
        ' only if all criteria matched is bMatch still True, and we add the sumrange cell
        If bMatch And IsNumeric(SumRange.Cells(x).Value2) Then dTotal = dTotal + SumRange.Cells(x).Value2
    Next x

    SumIfContains = dTotal

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you just need to iterate over the `ParamArray` `Step 2`. Add a test to make sure than the passed parameters come in pairs, then just grab them as a set of `Criteria` and `SumRange` in a loop:

```
Public Function PairedParamArrayIe(PhraseRange As Range, ParamArray values())

    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim Criteria As String
    Dim SumRange As Range

    If UBound(values) Mod 2 <> 1 Then
        Err.Raise -1, vbNullString, "Invalid ParamArray"
    End If

    For counter = LBound(values) + 1 To UBound(values) Step 2
        Criteria = values(counter - 1)
        Set SumRange = values(counter)
        Debug.Print Criteria
        Debug.Print SumRange.AddressLocal
    Next counter

End Function
```