# Application.run with more than 30 arguments

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel VBA. Does anyone know about a way to overcome the argument length limit of `Application.Run()`? (Or please suggest other function that can do the same job.)

Specific to my situation some of my constraints are:

- I need to specify the called function as a string
- The function is within a standard module
- It is a function, the return value is needed, so `Call()` will not work.

In any case, I do not want the parameter list of the called function to be changed (e.g. to variant array or `ParamArray`) since I have written some other functionalities which depend on the function declaration.

---

EDIT: In response to some of the comments below I can provide a simplified version of my project here (could be off the original question though). In fact the whole design is established and running smooth except for the 30-arg constrain.

The very ultimate goal is to enable the following spreadsheet function which can be called like `=mySpreadSheetFn("calledFn", "para1=abc", "para2=2002", ...)`. This will invoke the function `calledFn()` whose declaration may be:

`Function calledFn(Optional para1 As String = "P1", _ 
Optional para2 As Integer = 202, _ 
Optional para3 As Boolean = True)`

and the default argument will be replaced accordingly as specified in the `ParamArray` in the `mySpreadSheetFn()` call. Similarly there will be `calledFn2()` etc which an end user can use. So, there has to be an `Application.Run()` inside `mySpreadSheetFn()` .

And here are the function definitions:

```
Type paramInfo
    Val As Variant
    dataType As String 'can be Enum but let's forget it for this purpose
End Type

Function mySpreadSheetFunction(fnName As String, ParamArray otherParams())

Dim fnParams As Scripting.Dictionary
' getFnDefaultParams(fn): return the defaults and data types of fn's params
'   as a Dictionary. Each item is of type paramInfo (see above)
Set fnParams = getFnParams(fnName)

' For each specified arg check whether it exists for the function.
' If so, replaces the default value with the input value.
' If not exist, then just ignore it
' The problem is really not with this part so just know 
'    we have all the parameters resolved after the for-loop
For i = LBound(otherParams) To UBound(otherParams)
    Dim myKey As String
    myKey = Split(otherParams(i), "=")(0)
    If fnParams.Exists(myKey) Then
        ' parseParam() converts the input string into required data type
        fnParams(myKey).Val = parseParam(Split(otherParams(i), "=", 2)(1), _
                              fnParams(myKey).DataType _
                              )
    End If
Next

' Here is the issue since the call cannot go beyond 30 args
Dim lb As Integer: lb = LBound(fnParams)
Select Case UBound(fnParams) - LBound(fnParams) + 1
Case 1: Application.Run fnName, fnParams(lb).Val
Case 2: Application.Run fnName, fnParams(lb).Val, fnParams(lb + 1).Val
' Omitted, goes until Case 30
' What to do with Case 31??
End Select

' Some other operations for each call

End Function

' An example of function that can be called by the above mySpreadSheetFn()
Function calledFn(Optional para1 As String = "P1", _ 
    Optional para2 As Integer = 202, _ 
    Optional para3 As Boolean = True)

' needs to return value
calledFn = para1 & para2 * 1000

 End Function
```

There is hardly any room to change the front-end since this is how the user interface is desired.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What function requires more than 30 arguments?

Comment: can you give an example of what the arguments are?  Perhaps you can store values in cells and pass a single range.  Really going to need more information to give any meaningful suggestions.

Comment: This sounds more like a design problem.

Comment: If the parameters are all fairly simple types, you could pack them all into one pipe-delimited string (e.g. `Parms = parm1 & "|" & parm2 & "|" & ... & "|" & parm217`) and then unpack them in the called function (e.g. `ParmList = Split(parms,"|")`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a bit late, but if you transfer the method to a class, everything becomes much easier:

**Class "c1"**

```
Public Sub IHaveTooManyArguments(ParamArray params())
    Debug.Print "Refactor me!"
End Sub
```

**Module "Main"**

```
Public Sub CallIHaveTooManyArguments(fnName As String, ParamArray params())
    Dim o as new c1
    CallByName o, fnName, VbMethod, params
End Sub
```

Comment: This is indeed the method I used. Notice however that the direct use of params in CallByName will not work and I got around it thanks to this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313575/passing-an-array-of-arguments-to-callbyname-vba)

Answer (score 1):

Pack several arguments into an array.  Or pack several arguments into some sort of data document, like an Xml file/string, or a JSON file/string, or an ordinary text file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're determined to call a procedure with more that 30 parameters via `Application.Run`, you'll need a trampoline procedure in order to match its function signature.  Make a second prodecure that takes the parameters in an array (or some other package), and then pass that to a *second* procedure that calls the one with too many parameters:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim args As Variant
    args = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, _
                 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, _
                 31, 32)
    Application.Run "ToManyArgsTrampoline", "fnName", args
End Sub

Sub ToManyArgsTrampoline(fnName As String, args() As Variant)
    If UBound(args) = 31 Then
        IHaveTooManyArguments fnName, args(0), args(1), args(2), args(3), args(4), args(5), _
                              args(6), args(7), args(8), args(9), args(10), args(11), _
                              args(12), args(13), args(14), args(15), args(16), args(17), _
                              args(18), args(19), args(20), args(21), args(22), args(23), _
                              args(24), args(25), args(26), args(27), args(28), args(29), _
                              args(30), args(31)
    End If
End Sub

Sub IHaveTooManyArguments(fnName As String, ParamArray otherparams())
    Debug.Print "Refactor me!"
End Sub
```

Comment: This will require `IHaveTooManyArguments` to be hardcoded in the main, which is not very clean (consider there will be `IHaveTooMany2` etc). Can you suggest a way which can avoid that?

Comment: There isn't a way to avoid it.  You can't change `Application.Run`'s function signature (1 required parameter followed by 30 optional parameters) - period.

Comment: @user90957 - I just saw your edit (see my edit that matches your function signature).  This method still works (and AFAIK is the only way to pass a `ParamArray` through `Application.Run`.